# How to design an angular2 project

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have 2 html's

1) common-html.html

2) After-login.html

1) common-html.html--This is a layout page of my app because this contains my background image and little css.

```
  <section id="content" style="background-image: url('assets/images/bg.png');background-size: 100% auto;min-height: 100% !important;">
    <div class="content-wrap" [ngClass]="classmap">
            <div class="container clearfix">
                <div class="row  divcenter"   style="max-width:966px;background: #FFF;">
                        <router-outlet></router-outlet>   
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

2)This contains my navbar and side menu etc which should be appeared after login

```
  <header-Navbar></header-Navbar>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 nopadding backgrouncolordiv hidden-xs">
    <div class="margindivcss">
        <div class="col-xs-12 nopadding imgcontainer text-center">
            <img src="assets/images/no_image.png" class="imagewidth">
        </div>   
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <a class="pull-left usernameheading" href="#">{{name}}</a>
        <a class="pull-right" href="#"><i class="icon icon-pencil"></i></a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="user-list" >
        <ul class="fst-ul">
            <li><a [routerLink]="['/demo/profile']">PROFILE</a></li>
            <li><a [routerLink]="['/demo/social']">SOCIAL ADDRESSES</a></li>
            <li class="list-borbtom"><a [routerLink]="['/demo/custom']">CUSTOM INFO</a></li>
            <li><a   [routerLink]="['/demo/society']">MY SOCIETY<span>(ALL)</span></a></li>
                <ul class="left-sub-list">
                        <li><a [routerLink]="['/demo/society']" style="padding-left:15px" href="#">PERSONAL</a></li>
                        <li><a [routerLink]="['/demo/professional']" style="padding-left:15px"  href="#">PROFESSIONAL</a></li>
                </ul>
        </ul> 
    </div>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-7 topmargin-sm nopadding">
                    <router-outlet></router-outlet>       
            </div>
```

I am not sure what to do in main module.ts and main.ts and in index.html.Can anyone suggest help.Thanks.

Comment: what is the landing page for before login and after login?

Comment: I am using my profile.component as landing page through routes

Comment: update the post with a meaningful screenshot of the layout u r looking for and format your code for readability.

Answer (score 1):

If you're "completely helpless", it might be a good thing to look at Angular CLI, which does 99.99% of the initial setup for you and also includes some very helpful generators to add components, pipes, services, etc. to your project.

Have a look: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

**However**, if you're new to Angular (and that is why you are "helpless"), you should probably learn angular first.
Start with the [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) and make your way from there.

Comment: I would strongly advise against using Angular CLI as a complete beginner.  Before using a tool like this, you should first understand what the CLI is doing. Follow some tutorials (the official Tour of Heroes is good) and try to understand what each feature does and why they are required.